# regular expression -- greedy matching?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract a leading string by stripping off an optional trailing string, where the trailing strings are a subset of possible leading strings but not vice versa. Suppose the leading string is like `[a-z]+` and the trailing string is like `c`. Thus from "abc" I want to extract "ab", and from "ab" I also want to get "ab". Something like this:

```
^([a-z]+)(?:c|)
```

The problem is that the `[a-z]+` matches the entire string, using the empty option in the alternative, so the grabbed value is "abc" or "ab". (The `(?:` tells it not to grab the second part.) I want some way to make it take the longer option, or the first option, in the alternative, and use that to determine what matches the first part.

I have also tried putting the desired target inside both of the alternatives:

```
^([a-z]+)c|^([a-z]+)
```

I think that it should prefer to match the first one of the two possible alternatives, but I get the same results as above.

I am doing this in R, so I can use either the POSIX or the Perl regex library.

(The actual problem involves futures trading symbols. These have a root "instrument name" like `[A-Z0-9]+`, followed by an "expiration code" like `[FGHJKMNQUVXZ][0-9]{1,2}`. Given a symbol like "ZNH3", I want to strip the "H3" to get "ZN". But if I give it "ZN" I also want to get back "ZN".)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(c("abc", "abd"), "^(\\w+?)c?$", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "ab"  "abd"
```

and even easier:

```
> sub("c$", "", c("abc", "abd"))
[1] "ab"  "abd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working regular expression:

```
vec <- c("ZNH3", "ZN", "ZZZ33", "ABF")

sub("(\\w+)[FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\\d{1,2}", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "ZN" "ZN" "ZZ" "ABF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'non-greedy' match for the first part of the regex, followed by the definitions of your 'optional allowed suffixes' anchored by the 'end-of-string'...

This regex `(.+?)([FGHJKMNQUVXZ][0-9]{1,2})?$`matches...

- `(.+?)` as few characters as possible
- `([FGHJKMNQUVXZ][0-9]{1,2})?` followed by an allowable (but optional) suffix
- `$` followed by the end of string

The required result is in the first captured element of the match (however that may be referenced in 'r') :-)

Comment: Apologies for the PHP code, but the regex breakdown is still valid. Specifically: 'non-greedy match, followed by 'optional suffix', anchored by the 'end-of-string', I'll hack out the PHP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the non-greedy answers using base code only.

```
codes <- c("ZNH3", "CLZ4")
matched <- regmatches(codes, regexec("^([A-Z0-9]+?)[FGHJKMNQUVXZ][0-9]{1,2}$", codes))
# [[1]]
# [1] "ZNH3" "ZN"  
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "CLZ4" "CL"  
sapply(matched, `[[`, 2)  # extract just codes
# [1] "ZN" "CL"
```